# Ruby script throws error when run by cron, but not when run by user

Tags: ruby, csv, twitter, cron

I have a ruby script which scrapes a Twitter account, outputs to CSV, loads / cleans the CSV, and runs it through MarkyMarkov to generate @ebooks style tweets.

The script runs perfectly on my server when I run it manually from the command line, but when I run it via cron, it generates the following error:

```
usr/share/ruby/csv.rb:2058:in `=~': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
from /usr/share/ruby/csv.rb:2058:in `init_separators'
from /usr/share/ruby/csv.rb:1590:in `initialize'
from /usr/share/ruby/csv.rb:1376:in `new'
from /usr/share/ruby/csv.rb:1376:in `parse'
from script.rb:57:in `<main>'
```

Not sure why the result would differ between me running it and cron. Any suggestions on what is wrong or how to go about debugging? Ruby rookie here.

Comment: It sounds like the ruby version run in cron is older (pre-2.0), in which the default encoding is US-ASCII, and the user ruby is newer, in which the default encoding is UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using rbenv or RVM to manage your rubies, which load the Ruby reference from profile scripts, and cron doesn't load such profiles (e.g., `~/.bashrc`).

You should be able to do:

```
0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c '/path/to/your/script.rb'
```

This should load your user environment and run your script properly.

Also, I don't know if you are familiar with it, and it may be overkill for your situation, but the [Whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) provides a nice DSL for working with cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I ran into a similar issue and wanted to understand what was going on.

In my case I used a rvm wrapper around the script, which should be enough to provide the necessary environment. Nevertheless, I ran in the encoding issue. I found out that the locale was the bottle neck. Providing the proper locale was sufficient to solve this

```
0 * * * *  LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 /software/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.4.2@watcher/ruby /path/to/my/script.rb
```